# Combine two columns into one column

Tags: sql, join

I have two columns in one table. Let's say they are: Chelsea (as column1) and Brazil (as column2).

Rows in these two columns are players (both have 11 rows). As we know, there might be the case when the same player is in both columns (e.g. Ramirez, because he plays for Chelsea and is Brazilian). And my question is how to create a new column  in which every player from these two columns will appear (so this new column will have 22 rows, i.e. duplicates are allowed) and instead of their names, every row will be saying whether they are right- or left-footed players.

If football case doesn't appeal to you, let's say we have Miami Heat (column 1, 5 rows) and the US national team (column 2, 5 rows). In both columns, we will obviously have LeBron James and I would like to create a new table saying if every player is right- or left-handed (10 rows)

Hope anyone understands me ;)

Thanks for help!

Comment: none, I have just made up a case which would be relevant for my problem

Comment: What in case when basketball doesnt appeal also ?

Comment: Well, I have produced this basketball case just to present the same problem in different environment.

Comment: The tables you are describing have severe issues from normalization point of view. If this is a real application, consider a DB refactoring, so that you end up with a players table and a team table, which you can connect with a join table.

Comment: Could you list these "severe issues from normalization point of view"? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to combine result from of two columns you should use the union

```
Select column1 from table
union all
select column2 from table;
```

This will produce the result. As for the second part its defer from the db you use. But what you have to do is wrap about query into block and from that block in select part you should add a decision that do the job.

Comment: Sorry but no, from what I know, UNION will give you only unique values, but I need duplicates

Comment: IF you need duplicates that mean you are doing something wrong. But to achieve that use `union all`. Then you will have duplicates.

Comment: Because having redundant information is generally an issue then expected solution. So the question what advantage you will get from having duplicates ? If they are a medium step in result, you should reconsider another approach to remove this step of data duplication.

Comment: Because this one column is a part of three-column table in which these two other columns have different values for duplicates coming from this column

Comment: That was expected but the strategy you pick to solve the problem is way around than should be. If you care about information form 3rd and decision should be made based on column 1 and is possible that simple if statement in select. OR you db schema is really poor and that why you need this odd strategy to produce expected result.

Comment: What IF statement would you produce? And additionally, your statement with UNION ALL does not change the values of rows in this columns but just unions them. How to change the rows values into e.g. 'l' - for left-footed and 'r'- for right footed? I am trying with SET  and CASE WHEN but it is not working. Thanks